# Working with securityPolicies in the Compute Engine API in Python

Tags: python, rest, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to use the [securityPolicies API](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/compute/v1/python/latest/compute_v1.securityPolicies.html) for the Google Cloud Platform in Linux in a script written in Python.

To do this:

I installed [google-api-python-client](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/libraries#google_apis_python_client_library):

```
 pip install google-api-python-client
```

I generated and downloaded from GCP this credential information (private key) in JSON format and exported the path to this file under the environmental variable:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='[PATH]'
```

Now I have a doubt about how to properly use the `google-api-python-client` library to achieve my goal.

Using the [`addRule` method according to the documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/compute/v1/python/latest/compute_v1.securityPolicies.html#addRule) I write the following script (of course with valid values for `project` keys and `securityPolicy`), but when I execute it, although the interpreter doesn't return any error, but the script doesn't give the expected effect:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
compute_service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1')
security_policies = compute_service.securityPolicies()
security_policies.addRule(
    project='existed_project_name',
    securityPolicy='existed_security_policy_name',
    body={
        'kind': 'compute#securityPolicyRule',
        'priority': 303,
        'action': 'deny(403)',
        'preview': False,
        'match': {
            'config': {
                'srcIpRanges': [
                    '192.0.2.0/24',
                    '198.51.100.0/24',
                    '203.0.113.0/24'
                ]
            },
            'versionedExpr': 'SRC_IPS_V1'
        }
    }
)
```

So I have the following **questions**:

**1. What should I improve or change?**

**2. Is my approach to authentication correct?**

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you describe what happened when you executed the script? What was the unexpected behavior? I can do more troubleshooting with that and also if this is the entire script, I'd like to reproduce the behavior. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your response and interest in @SamuelN. What I would like to achieve is the addition of a new rule with those sample IPs for Cloud Armor on production. Unfortunately, nothing like this happens, although the script does not return any error. To reproduce my real situation, you can just execute the above fragment of the script with real `existed_project_name` and `existed_security_policy_name` (which I have not put in here for obvious reasons) and observe that the script does not work. Do you need more @SamuelN details from me? If so, ask boldly. I will try to answer everything.

Comment: The authentication part should be okay. To be sure, can you try to Verify authentication [1]? [1]: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#verifying_authentication

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `.execute()` at the end of your `addRule` method

So your code should look like this:

```py
from googleapiclient import discovery
compute_service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1')
security_policies = compute_service.securityPolicies()
security_policies.addRule(
    project='existed_project_name',
    securityPolicy='existed_security_policy_name',
    body={
        'kind': 'compute#securityPolicyRule',
        'priority': 303,
        'action': 'deny(403)',
        'preview': False,
        'match': {
            'config': {
                'srcIpRanges': [
                    '192.0.2.0/24',
                    '198.51.100.0/24',
                    '203.0.113.0/24'
                ]
            },
            'versionedExpr': 'SRC_IPS_V1'
        }
    }
).execute()
```